# Name for function that is Lipschitz continuous over partitioning of input space

Tags: metric-spaces, lipschitz-functions, continuity

Let $f: X \to \mathbb R$ and $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Let $P=\{P_1,P_2,\dotsc\}$ be a *countable* partitioning of $X$. I would like to assume that $f$ is Lipschitz continuous on $(P_i,d)$ for all $P_i \in P$, but not necessarily over $(X,d)$. Is there a standard word or phrase that describes this sort of function?

Comment: Standard word, no. For a standard phrase, what you wrote when describing $f$.

Comment: The term *countably Lipschitz* would be a reasonable choice, but this apparently already means something else (your notion when a "small" exceptional set is allowed). I'll look through my books at home this evening and let you know tomorrow if I find anything.

Comment: You could define the term "piecewise Lipschitz with respect to $P$", and use it.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I like piecewise Lipschitz with respect to $P$. Not being a mathematician I was worried that if I did something like that reviewers would say "clearly that's just a needless new word for a Dothraki-continuous function". It sounds like that won't happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on my yesterday's comment . . .

There are two well-known (in classical real analysis) similar notions in S. Saks [**Theory of the Integral**](https://archive.org/details/theoryoftheinteg032192mbp) (1937), *VBG* (generalized bounded variation, p. 221) and *ACG* (generalized absolutely continuous, p. 223). A function $f:[a,b] \rightarrow {\mathbb R}$ is *VBG* if there exists a countable partition of $[a,b]$ such that the restriction of $f$ to each set in this partition has bounded variation on that set, and similarly for *ACG*. I haven't tried to track down the origin of these notions, but I doubt it would be very difficult to do so if there is any interest.

Anyway, two relatively recent books make use of the more general notion "$f:E \rightarrow {\mathbb R}$ is *PG*", where $E \subseteq {\mathbb R}$ and *P* is some property that $f$ and any of its restrictions can have (e.g. bounded variation, absolute continuity, Lipschitz, etc.) --- **[Real Functions – Current Topics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540600086)** by Vasile Ene (see Definition 1.9.2, and see *LG* for *P* = Lipschitz on p. 58) and [**Theory of Differentiation**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471253871) by Krishna M. Garg (see Section 1.3 on pp. 15-16).

However, I think the use of "generalized" in this context is not likely to be all that well known (or guessable) to those not steeped in a background of classical real analysis, and I suggest maybe using something like $\sigma$-*Lipschitz function* if you have to refer to the notion a lot and want a short suggestive term. The idea is that what you want is a countable union of Lipschitz functions, the union being over the ordered pairs that define the functions.

I also saw the term "*countably m rectifiable" used in [**Geometric Measure Theory**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540606564) by Herbert Federer (3.2.14 on p. 251) for a *set* in ${\mathbb R}^{m}$ that is a countable union of images of Lipschitz functions, but not the idea of a *function* being a countable union of Lipschitz functions.